# MathJax breaks my indentation

Tags: bug, status-deferred, mathjax, markdown

Seems like there is a bug, that breaks my indentation.

**See**

1. In third code section of
   [Create New C++ Class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80598/create-new-c-class)
2. In first code section of
   [Code Generator Generator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79577/code-generator-generator)

   [image]
3. multiple times in the code section of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/84104/ (Perl syntax naturally includes both `\$` and `$$`).

This occurs on both block delimiters and inline delimiters. Live minimal test case:

```
$$
b0rked
$$
```

and

```
\$
b0rked
\$
```

In the [Markdown source](/posts/5063/edit), all lines are vertically aligned, not additionally indented

Comment: Hmmm... I can reproduce it, and do not understand why it is broken.....

Comment: Yikes, creepy....

Comment: reproduced on our dev environment, it's mathjax related, happens when we're baking a post's markdown to html, looking into it

Comment: @m0sa has there been any progress on this problem? I was baffled why my code – even in the editor preview – had this random extra indentation. That kind of sucks for a site that's about clean code, which involves proper formatting.

Comment: @amon I looked into it, turned out to be a deep rabbit hole requiring at major refactoring of MarkdownSharp (we'd need to make the pipeline extensible, so we could inject stuff before [DoCodeBlocks in RunBlockGamut](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/browse/MarkdownSharp/Markdown.cs#382) - currently all the processing happens before we ever hit MarkdownSharp, but we'd need to leverage it's block processing)

Comment: [Similar issue from PPCG](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5043/3808). /cc @m0sa

Answer (score 13):

This seems to happen because of the above line having two `$` in a row.

```
static std::string TOKEN_LINEDUMP("$$
    static std::string TOKEN_INDENTNEXT("$$>");
```

Removing the second `$` on the first line causes it to be shown normal:

```
static std::string TOKEN_LINEDUMP("$
static std::string TOKEN_INDENTNEXT("$$>");
```

Further investigation is needed.

Comment: is this related to mathjax??

Comment: Actually, removing any of the `$` will stop the indentation.  This does make it look like a MathJax issue.

Comment: FYI, this is not due to MathJax itself since MathJax stops parsing at HTML elements, so it won't touch `<span class="str">"$$&gt;"</span>` etc. However, it could have something to do with the way StackExchange's editor isolates LaTeX-input from the Markdown processor.

Comment: Could we not have some `<!-- mathjax:off -->` magic comment to switch off MathJax on top of a code block?